# How to paste values in a variable that are based conditionally on values in another different variable in r?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have searched on stack overflow for examples similar to the problem I am facing and am stuck, so any help would be appreciated! I have a dataframe that is similar to the one below:

`df <- data.frame( "ID" = c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6), rep(3,5), rep(4,5)), "A" = c(0, rep(0,4),1 ,rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0,3), 1, rep(0,2), 1, rep(0,3)), "count" = NA)`

and I would like to edit the "count" variable so the dataframe looks like this:

`df2 <- data.frame( "ID" = c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6), rep(3,5), rep(4,5)), "A" = c(0, rep(0,4),1 ,rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0,3), 1, rep(0,2), 1, rep(0,3)), "count" = c(NA, NA, -3:-1,1, NA, NA, -3:-1,1, -3:-1, 1:2, -1, 1:3, NA ))`

Within each `df$ID`, when `df$A = 1` I need `df$count = 1`. Additionally, I need `df$count` to count forward from 1:3 and count backwards from -1:-3, omitting zero so df2 is produced. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which gives you the desired sequence :

```
library(dplyr)

add_num <- function(x) {
  #Get the index of 1
  inds <- which(x == 1)
  #Create a sequence with that index as 0
  num <- lapply(inds, function(i) {
    num <- seq_along(x) - i
    #Add 1 to values greater than equal to 0
    num[num >= 0] <- num[num >= 0] + 1
    num[num < -3 | num > 3] <- NA
    num
  })
  #Select the first non-NA values from the sequence
  do.call(coalesce, num)
}
```

now apply this function each `ID` :

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(count = add_num(A))

#   ID A count
#1   1 0    NA
#2   1 0    NA
#3   1 0    -3
#4   1 0    -2
#5   1 0    -1
#6   1 1     1
#7   1 0     2
#8   1 0     3
#9   1 0    NA
#...
#...
#46  4 0    NA
#47  4 0    NA
#48  4 0    -3
#49  4 0    -2
#50  4 0    -1
#51  4 1     1
#52  4 0     2
#53  4 0     3
#54  4 0    NA
#55  4 0    -3
#56  4 0    -2
#57  4 0    -1
#58  4 1     1
#59  4 0     2
```

Comment: This is really helpful! However, I am running into a problem when I apply this function to my full dataframe. In my dataframe there are several instances when 1 appears in the A column more than once. When 1 appears more than once, it is not within the span of 3 consecutive zeroes above and below it, so the 'count' should repeat after some NAs, but this is not happening with this function.

Comment: I think this should still work if 1 appears more than once. The issue could be if there is no 1 at all in a group. Anyway, can you update your post with data using which we can reproduce the error/incorrect output that you are getting?

Comment: `df <- data.frame( "ID" = c(rep(1,12), rep(2,13), rep(3,15), rep(4,19)), "A" = c(rep(0,5), 1, rep(0,5) ,rep(0, 10), 1, rep(0,12), 1, rep(0,15), 1, rep(0,6), 1, 0), "count" = NA)` Here is a dataframe in which there are 2 1's in A for the ID 4. When I apply the function you created, the second 1 has no adjust values in the count variable.

Comment: @nagpal826 I see, so you want to generate the sequence at all the places where there is 1. See updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this question. However when I apply this code to a much larger data frame (14306 obs) I get the following error:
```> test <- test %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(count = add_num(A))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `count`.
x At least one argument must be supplied.
i Input `count` is `add_num(A)`.
i The error occurred in group 11: ID = 212.```